# If $X, Y$ are random vectors, is it true that $E[g(X,Y)] = E[E[g(X,Y)| \{Y: AY \geq b\}]]$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are random vectors. By the law of iterated expectation, does the following hold?

$$E[g(X,Y)] = E[E[g(X,Y)| \{Y: AY \geq b\}]],$$

where $g(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a function, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are a matrix and vector of constants, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct in general because the event $AY\geq b$ is not a partition of the whole space. Let's say the $Y$ vectors satisfying this relationship constitute the set $\mathcal Y$. Then, the correct relation is
$$E[g(X,Y)]=E[g(X,Y)|Y\in \mathcal Y]P(Y\in \mathcal Y)+E[g(X,Y)|Y\notin \mathcal Y]P(Y\notin \mathcal Y)$$

A simple counter-example: let $g(X,Y)=Y$, and let $Y$ be a Bernoulli RV (with parameter $p$), so $n=1$. Furthermore, let $A=b=1$. Then, we have
$$E[E[g(X,Y)|\{Y:Y\geq 1\}]]=E[E[g(X,Y)]|Y=1]=E[1]=1$$

However, the correct answer is $p$, i.e. $E[g(X,Y)]=E[Y]=p$

P.S. I'm assuming $\geq$ operation is defined properly between $n\times1$ vectors.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're defining $\mathcal{Y} = \{Y: AY \geq b\}$, correct?

Comment: Correct, the set of $Y$ satisfying $AY\geq b$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also explain how you know that "in general the event $AY \geq b$ is not a partition of the whole space"?

Comment: Well, it's a condition on $Y$, and will most probably decrease the amount of possibilities for it.

Comment: I see. If $Y$ is continuous, can the space of $Y$ be partitioned into $\mathcal{Y}$ and $\mathcal{Y}^c$, where $\mathcal{Y}$ is the set of $Y$ satisfying $AY \geq b$?

Comment: Yes, my example was discrete just because of convenience.

Comment: Thanks. So $E[g(X, Y)| Y \in \mathcal{Y}]$ is still a function of $Y$, correct?

Comment: No, it's scalar because condition is like $Y\geq 1$